# "In appropriate time" or "In THE appropriate time"?

Tags: word-usage

Which one is correct ?
I mean should we use "THE" between "in" and "appropriate" or not ?

Comment: This question cannot be properly answered without more context.

Comment: What @Mr. Shiny and New said. Most likely OP should be using [in **good** time](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-good-time) anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No "the".  It isn't wrong but you already have a descriptor for time in appropriate.  The stress should be on appropriate and "the" would take a little away from it.  Also try not to use words that don't add to your sentence.

Answer (score 1):

"*At* the appropriate time" may be more appropriate the either - what's the context?

Comment: It's formal and about ACM computing contests . I want to say that the server should respond to the solutions in appropriate time .

Comment: Then maybe *within an appropriate time*.  My *at...* wouldn't suit as you're talking about elapsed time, rather than a fixed time  as I was thinking of.

Comment: Oh, it's a computer term. Like in polynomial time. So do you mean "appropriate" in the sense of "fast enough", or do you mean "appropriate" in the sense of "what is predicted by theory"? If it's the last, then perhaps a more descriptive and less judgemental term than "appropriate" would be better. Perhaps a phrase.

Comment: Thank you john ! I mean "fast enough" , I think the "appropriate" would suit the article ! Thanks!